# How to make a generic class a property in another instance class?

Tags: c#, generics, static, constructor

I'm totally new to C# generic so I have the following problem. I have 2 classes. One instance based and another generic class.
I want to have a property in the 1st class of the type of 2nd generic class.

something on these lines....functionality wise.

```
public class SampleClass
{
  private SampleGenericClass<T> sampleClass;

   public SampleClass(string name, int age, string version)
   {
     if(version == "1.0")
     {
       this.sampleClass = new SampleGenericClass<int>(name, age);
     }
     else
     {
       this.sampleClass = new SampleGenericClass<long>(name.age);
     }
   }

  public void Load()
  {
    this.sampleClass.Load();
  }
  public void Open()
  {
    this.sampleClass.Open();
  }
  public void Close()
  {
    this.sampleClass.Close();
  }
}
```

My 2nd generic class is something like this

```
  internal class SampleGenericClass<T> where T : class
  {
    private string name;
    private string age;

    public SampleGenericClass(string name, int age)
    {
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
    }

    public void Load()
    {
      // Do something based on type
      if(typeof(T) == typeof(int))
      {
        // load int type
      }
      else if(typeof(T) == typeof (long))
      {
        // load long type
      }
      else
      {
        throw new ArgumentException("Un supported type");
      }
    }
    public void Open()
    {
      // Do something based on type
      if(typeof(T) == typeof(int))
      {
        // open int type
      }
      else if(typeof(T) == typeof (long))
      {
        // open long type
      }
      else
      {
        throw new ArgumentException("Un supported type");
      }
    }

    public void Close()
    {
      // Do something based on type
      if(typeof(T) == typeof(int))
      {
        // close int type
      }
      else if(typeof(T) == typeof (long))
      {
        // close long type
      }
      else
      {
        throw new ArgumentException("Un supported type");
      }
    }       

  }
```

Now I understand that CLR doesnt support generic properties or constructors.
So how can I solve this problem? I still want to have a generic class and somehow instantiate it in my 2nd class based on the params passed to constructor of 1st class, so as to call the methods load,openm, close in the 2nd class .

Thanks for your help.

NOTE: I know the above code doesn't compile, bcoz CLR doesnt support generic properties and constructors. It's just for illustrative purpose of what I want to achieve conceptually

Comment: You have a design flow in your program. If you know the types you are going to use (`int` and `long`) then just go for creating an abstract class with two implementations, one that takes `int`s and the other will take `long`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO you should decide in upper level, what is the type of SampleClass In fact you should define it as generic:

```
public class SampleClass<T> where T : ....
{
  private SampleGenericClass<T> sampleClass;

   public SampleClass(string name, int age, string version)
   {
       this.sampleClass = new SampleGenericClass<T>(name, age);
   }

  public void Load()
  {
    this.sampleClass.Load();
  }
}
```

and create your SampleClass base on version in upper levels(and related generic).

e.g:

Main method:

```
if (version == "1")
{
    DoAction<int>();
}
else
  DoAction<long>();

.....
void DoAction<T>()
{
   SampleClass<T> s = new SampleClass<T>(...)
}
```

Also as I can see you don't need T type for your member variables, so you can move it to lower level in function calls.

Answer (score 2):

Either declare a concrete type

```
public class SampleClass {   
    private SampleGenericClass<int> sampleClass; 
    ...
}
```

or add a generic type parameter to `SampleClass`

```
public class SampleClass<T> where T : class {   
    private SampleGenericClass<T> sampleClass; 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Interface:

```
 public interface ISampleGenericClass
  {
        void Load();
        void Open();
        void Close();
  }
```

The generic class implements this:

```
internal class SampleGenericClass<T> : ISampleGenericClass
{
   ...
}
```

And SampleClass

```
public class SampleClass
{
  private ISampleGenericClass sampleClass;
....
}
```

I removed the class constraint, because int and long are value types, so they can't be used in the current form.